# mod_rewrite remapping folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've currently updated our site, and the image folder name has changed from `/img/` to `/images/`.

I'm still getting 404 errors in my apache error log from bots etc trying to access the old `/img` folder.

I'm trying to write a mod_rewrite rule to redirect any attempts to access `/img/` to refer to `/images/`.

This is what I've got so far:

```
RewriteRule ^img/?(.*)$ images/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, whenever I access http://mysite.com/img I still get my 404 page (instead of a forbidden page which I should receive for accessing /images).

Is this correct? I do have another rule forcing use of ssl if that matters.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule should be place on your root folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) /images/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

This rule will redirect only existent files or folders  existent on `http://domain.com/images`.

Keep in mind that you may have been cached from previous attempts since you're using `R=301`, so to make sure its working try using a different browser.

Note that I am using `R=302`, to avoid this caching, once you confirm it is working, change it to `R=301`.